# Slick 3.0 Mapping to a List

Tags: slick

I have a mapping definition in Slick as below:

```
class MyTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[MyTableRwo](tag, "myTable") {

 def id = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
 def otherTableIds = column[Seq[Long]]("ids")
}
```

The other table looks like:

```
class MyOtherTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[MyOtherTableRow](tag, "myOtherTable") {

  def id = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def myTableId = // this is a foreign key to the MyTable
}
```

where the def otherTableIds should come from another table called MyOtherTable. MyTable has a one-to-many relationship with the MyOtherTable. What I would want Slick to do is to get only the Id's of the MyOtherTable when I load the MyTable for a given id!

Any clues?

Comment: Could you give the other table definition? Is there a foreign key?

Comment: Ok I added the other table definition!